# C++ what does << and >> mean in simple terms

Tags: c++, cout, cin

in C++ when you do

```
int a;
std::cin >> a;
std::cout << a;
```

it prints a.  What exactly goes on with << and >> when inputing and outputting, in simple terms please.  I saw the answers to a similar questions and dont really understand the jargon they used. And are there any other ways to use << and >>?

Comment: This has to do with operator overloading, they have been chosen because when you write `cout << a`, `<<` would suggest you an arrow to inject `a` onto `cout`.

Comment: What does cout do once it has a?

Comment: `cout` is the C++ object that is used to stringify values into it. In general cout represent the terminal (but this can be redirected to somzthing else). This is a way to *print something on screen*.

Comment: What causes the stuff you put into it to be printed onto the screen, and not just saved into the cout?

Comment: Lot of questions... Last answer. cout is an open file, you write things into it. If cout is plugged onto the screen, it *prints* it to the screen, if it is plugged to a *real* file it saves it into it. I think you lack a lot of computer related concepts.

Comment: This question is exceptionally hard to answer: "What *exactly* happens in *simple* terms."

Comment: This is one of things you have to just take for granted as a beginner and learn how it works later on.

Comment: @codersarecool Yvou might have a look at the actual implementation, to get a grip what's going along under the hood.  The way it is, your question is _unclear_, _too broad_ respectively.

Comment: @codersarecool _"And are there any other ways to use << and >>?"_ Sure there are, these operators do bit shifting when used with integer numeric operands.

Answer (score 7):

It's syntactic sugar. What is actually called is:

```
int a;
operator>>(std::cin, a);
operator<<(std::cout, a);
```

Now, what happens inside these operators for built in types, in simple terms is hard to explain.

In rough terms:

- `operator<<` converts its input to characters/bytes and sends those
  bytes to its associated device which usually is the terminal.
- `operator>>` reads text/bytes from its associated device (e.g.,
  keyboard) and transforms them to their respective built in type
  representation.

This schematically can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: Oh, what goes on in those statements?

Comment: @codersarecool for built in types a lot of stuff.

Comment: Hidden behind << and >> are literally dozens of functions all doing different things to take different types of data, convert them to or from text, and read them from or write them to a stream. `cin` and `cout` are two of many possible streams that can be used. Trying to explain them all is way out of scope for SO.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `>>` and `<<` are binary operators, like `-` or `+`.

They generally mean to invoke a function declared like

```
C operator << (A a, B b)
```

You can overload this like any other operator to do whatever you want, if you want to make a fancy big integer class and give it shift operators for example.

When you use it with an ostream like `std::cout` it generally calls a function with a signature like this:

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &, const B & b)
```

It means, to write the second argument `b` to the stream given as first argument, and return it. So

```
std::cout << "a" << "b" << "c"
```

means something like

```
output(output(output(std::cout, "a"), "b"), "c")
```

if the function were given a "conventional" name `output` instead of using operator overloading.

`std::cin` is similar, you need to ask a more precise question if you want more detailed info I think.

Comment: What does overload, shift operator, and ostream mean?

Comment: I think you have to research that yourself, you can look on any C++ reference site or wikipedia, or a text book, for definitions / introductions to that stuff. they will give a better explanation than I can here. they are basic features of the language / standard library

Comment: @codersarecool You're trying to munch a too big bite you've been hitting apparently. Stack Overflow probably isn't the right site to give you all about the basics about operator functions, and how to overload them.

Answer (score 0):

"std::cin >> a;" - it converted to std::istream& std::istream::operator>>(a);
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

"std::cout << a;" - it converted to std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(a);
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses the concept of [Operator Overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), which means that for any given object, you can specify functions that are called by invoking any of the given operators upon it.

One of the classical examples would be a `complex` class, designed to handle complex numbers. You might, for example, define two `complex` numbers:

```
complex a(1,0.5); // 1+.5i
complex b(-2.5,1); // -2.5 + i
```

In a programming language that doesn't have operator overloading, you'd write an add function like this:

```
complex add(complex b) {
    return complex(r + b.r, i + b.i);
}
```

And invoke it like this:

```
complex c = a.add(b);//This technically invokes an operator overload on the '=' sign, but just bear with me.
```

However, with operator overloading, you can instead write the function like this:

```
complex operator+(complex b) {
    return complex(r + b.r, i + b.i);
}
```

And perform the addition like this:

```
complex c = a + b;
```

In the case of output/input streams, they have had their `operator<<` and `operator>>` functions defined to perform specialized tasks on their objects. So you can invoke `cout << mynum` and `mynum` will be appended to the end of the stream.